# Why doesn't my csv-file write all the rows to txt-files in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, txt, export-csv

I am trying to save each row in my dataframe to a separate txt-file, with the content in one of the columns named after the other column. I got it to work but it only saves 4445 rows out of 46000. Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong?

This is the code i am using:

```
file = 'Test_dir/{}.txt'

for i in df.index:
    content = df["content"][i]
    name = df["name"][i]
    with open(file.format(name), "w") as f:
        f.write(content)
```

Comment: Are all the names different?

Comment: first use `print()` to see values in variable - maybe it helps you see if there is wrong value. You could also check first if `df.index` really gives you `46000` values - ie. `len(df.index)` or `df.index.shape`. Maybe better you should use `for row in df.iterrows():`

Comment: No, I just recognize that a lot of the names are the same. So that might be the problem. @Barmar

Comment: Open the file in `a` mode to add to it instead of overwriting.